# How to dynamically refer to kivy widgets?

Tags: python, kivy

Trying to get my head around referring to multiple widgets with a variable. For instance:

```
#.kv
Button:
    id: button1

Button:
    id: button2

Button:
    id: button2

#.py
for x in range(3):
    self.ids.button[x].text = "This is button " + x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's maybe simplest to just use the fact that self.ids is a dict (+ getattr stuff):

```
for x in range(3):
    self.ids['button{}'.format(x)].text = 'This is button {}'.format(x)
```

You probably could also do it with getattr:

```
for x in range(3):
    getattr(self.ids, 'button{}'.format(x)).text = 'This is button {}'.format(x)
```

Comment: What exactly is happening in this syntax - Python is substituting the {} with the value of x I guess... but why is this happening, I've not seen this before? And why is there no leading . before the ['button... ?

Comment: The replacement is done by the .format() method - you can look this up in the documentation, it's a standard way to do string interpolation in python. And there's no . before the [ because the [ is another piece of syntax to access a specific value. You should check the normal python doc and tutorials to understand these things.